# Will you use 2010 Foundation on a Client 

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation

Now that 2010 Foundation Server can run on a client I am curious how many people will primarily develop locally versus on a server (or VM).

I like the idea of having the tools easily accessible, but I think I'll likely continue to use the server for the bulk of my dev work even if it doesn't require all of the services of the full Server version.

Comment: @next_connect: I've marked this question as community wiki as there isn't really an answer to it and it has a discussion feel. See http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/432/what-does-community-wiki-mean for more info.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking / planning on continuing to use a VM.  What I love about using a VM is even when I get a new laptop, all I need to do is copy my vm over and I'm up and going again. I also like the snapshotting / differencing disks as well.

I think the dev on a client will be nice for some of my co-workers who will be only sometimes developing in SP.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I will install it just for personal use (SP can also be very useful in a non-business context!), where I play the role of power user.

I will definately **not** be using it for development! For development I want an environment that is as indentical as possible to the environment I will be deploying to, which obviously runs on a server OS.

Comment: im 100% with you! I even heard of a dev team in UK that pulls the image from int-test every week back to the developer boxes (automated with powershell ofcourse) to get the dev rigs to look as much as the real servers as possible :-)

Answer (score 0):

I will continue to use a VM based server OS to develop on. Particularly because you end up hooking into other server technologies when building solutions which invariably you cannot run on a Windows client OS. Plus it takes quite a long time to get the environment right with all the tools/settings you need!

However, I am planning to move away from VMs running on my laptop to a dedicated virtual development server as its start to get toooo slloooowww.

Comment: I gave up developing on laptops a year ago. Ordered a nice dual quad-xeon with SAS disks and a bunch of ram and never looked back :-)

Comment: Nice ;) - I think I will be doing the same thing very shortly, did you buy off the shelf or build?

Answer (score 0):

Im gonna continue with VM/HyperV server development.

The problem is really, that doing development on a client OS is that it doesnt in any way resemble the dev-test environment. Hence you will see all sorts of "it works on my box" issues, because the developer sits on his client instead of on a similar (optimally created from same golden image) server than the dev-test/int-test/pre-prod/prod servers (eg. same version of RAD editor, same regional settings..).

Also its so cool to be just able to fire up a test WCM site, or a test portal, do a few tests and return to the old snapshot.

For demo purposes or demonstrations on the other hand, a laptop with Win7 would absolutely be a good alternative, but as Jaap say: never for real development.